# Bloomberg Terminal Excel Command For Option Chain On Specific Day

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I am trying to get the tickers for all options traded on a specific trading day for an underlying asset (such as Apple).

I have tried to find the command online however could not find any related articles. As I am accessing through a university account I cannot use the helpdesk either.

My current code is:

`=BDS(“AAPL US Equity”, “OPT_CHAIN”)`

My interpretation of this is that it displays all the tickers for the current trading day - not entirely sure. However I would like to specify a trading day such as 08/12/2023.

If historical data for this is unavailable, could I still specify for example the last trading day?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `=BDS("AAPL US Equity","OPT_CHAIN","SINGLE_DATE_OVERRIDE","20230812","ARRAY",TRUE)` with date YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: I’ll check this when I next use the terminal, thank you so much in the meantime!

Comment: I was able to use the terminal today and thank you it works! However, I ended up removing “ARRAY”, TRUE. 

Also, some options don’t have any volume and just end up using up my search limit. Would it be possible to filter and only keep the options that were traded with positive volume within that day?